# Why did .NET's EnableDecompression default value change between 2.0 and 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, base-class-library

We use .NET Web Services--both non-WCF and WCF, though the overwhelming majority is non-WCF, for legacy reasons--pretty heavily, and as I was testing something in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), I noticed that the response body size was pretty large. Then I noticed that the request headers didn't have any `Accept-Encoding` headers.

After doing some digging, it appears that the default value for the property `HttpWebClientProtocol.EnableDecompression` (from the class of which all `wsdl.exe`-originated WS stubs derive) *changed* between .NET BCL versions [2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.enabledecompression%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.enabledecompression%28VS.85%29.aspx). I'm curious as to the reason (which may be WCF-related), and further as to whether there are any other [pretty] fundamental changes that are pretty quiet when you simply link against a different library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/103330/enabledecompression-does-not-remove-acceptencoding-gzip-header) link.  The first comment from Microsoft states the following:

> Please also note that as part of the
>   fixed we changed the default value of
>   EnableDecompression to be false by
>   default. We were concerned that having
>   it on by default would break existing
>   customers that had implemented
>   decompression on top of ASP.NET Web
>   Services in v1.1.

It looks like the change was a result of a bug that they needed to fix.